# Why do we use rvm alias?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

Why do we use "rvm alias create default ruby-2.X.X"?

I see ruby-2.X.X@global and ruby-2.X.X in /usr/local/rvm directory.

If we have multiple rails apps running on the same ruby version and bundler is taking care of the different gem versions, can't we just do "rvm install ruby-2.X.X && rvm use ruby-2.X.X --default" and be done with it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `rvm alias` feature but I do use `rbenv alias` extensively, which I imagine is similar.

One purpose of aliases is to save typing. Instead of typing `rbenv shell 2.7.1` I could type `rbenv shell 2.7`. Saves 2 characters each time.

Another purpose of aliases is to provide a constant name/identifier for something that is variable. For example, "default" could refer to different versions over time, but a script that uses "default" would keep working throughout.